# Drawing a cross through the center of an image in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I am new in MatLab and I want to know how can I draw a cross through the center of an image. I know how to read the image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you read the image into a matrix named `img`, you could do this to draw a black cross:

```
img(:, round(end/2), :) = 0;
img(round(end/2), :, :) = 0;
```

If all you want is to draw a cross, without modifying the image, you could do it using `plot`, like this:

```
[nl, nc, ~] = size(img);
imshow(img);
hold on
plot([.5 .5] * nc, [0 nl]);
plot([0 nc], [.5 .5] * nl);
hold off
```

Comment: You're right, I'll edit my answer with an alternative solution using `plot`.

Comment: that's fine! thank you for your help!! both answers are helpful for me!